# Epplus 5.6: how to ignore a row when Exporting ToDataTable

Tags: c#, excel, ms-office, epplus

in this code i'm importing data from excel worksheet to a datatable using Epplus 5.6.4

```
 using(var report = new ExcelPackage(report_path))
    {    
      var x_sheet = report.Workbook.Worksheets["sheet1"];
      var dt_x_sheet = x_sheet.Cells["A:F"].ToDataTable();
    }
```

I'm getting the following error:

> **System.InvalidOperationException: 'Value cannot be null, row: 474, col: 5**

- how to import the data even if a cell has a null value.
- How to import the data and exclude the rows that has a specific cell condition, for example exclude the row if column 5 has a null value.

Answer (score -1):

This was a bug in EPPlus and has been fixed in 5.7.